# Disable a toolbar handler direct after execution

Tags: rcp, e4

I want to disable my toolbar handle directly after the execution. I saved in the past in e3, the `IAction` object via the "**selectionChanged**" method and so I set after the run logic the **action.setEnabled(false)**.

```java
public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    this.delegate = action;
}
```

Exist in e4 any possibility to do the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `@CanExecute` method of a handler to control the enablement.

```java
@CanExecute
public boolean canExecute()
{
  // TODO return enablement
}
```

This method is called when most things that could change the enablement run, or you can force it to be run by calling

```java
@Inject
IEventBroker eventBroker;


eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID);
```